# Best way to serialize a wpf element tree to Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What is the best way to serialize a wpf element tree to xaml so that I can get a design time representation?

XamlWriter.Save is having serious limitations, and it can provide only the run-time representation

Probably Microsoft don't want any one to build a customized xaml designer with out much effort :(

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, there is no direct way to get the design time representation of xaml from the visual tree. :)

Comment: Yep, that is what we are doing. The whole idea is to see whether we can work against the visual tree, or to provide a custom dom. We ended up with a custom dom. Thanks

Comment: But you know Custom dom has high maintenance - how are you going to manage that?

Comment: The custom dom is based on a configuration, so we need to maintain the configuration :)

Answer (score 0):

You can study the source code of Mole and create your own code that can do it for you.

[Mole For Visual Studio - With Editing - Visualize All Project Types](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx)

Comment: Already had a look in to Mole, it is creating only the run time xaml representation

Answer (score 0):

We have a XAML designer product which emplores a custom XAML serializer.  As it is, that is the most useful solution for us.  However, with .Net 4, there are a lot of great options (and helpers) for doing exactly that task.  So, if you're not afraid of a little betaness, I would start looking there.

Check out what [Guy Burstein](http://blogs.msdn.com/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx) has to say about it.

Answer (score -1):

Just un clip the xml unit eliminator and reroute both partial array procedures into the wpf tree. then create the object as a time line.

simples

Comment: you can make that joke more entertaining with an example